# How to get the values for C1 and C2 in Chan-Vese Model?

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, image-segmentation

This question will consider the widely accepted segmentation algorithm of Chan-Vese, given in the following publications:

> T.F. Chan, L.A. Vese, *An active contour model without edges*, Lecture
>   Notes in Computer Science, vol. 1682, pp. 141–151, 1999.
>
> T.F. Chan, L.A. Vese, *Active Contours Without Edges*, IEEE
>   Transactions on Image Processing, vol. 10, no. 1, pp. 266–277, 2001

The main publication is accessible here:
http://www.math.ucla.edu/~lvese/PAPERS/IEEEIP2001.pdf

Equation 6 and 7 of this paper mentions $c_1$ and $c_2$ values. The energy function is also parameterized by these variables. My question involves the algorithm / method to compute these values. How can I do that?

Comment: @Tolga Birdal, your good will is heart warming!

Answer (score 1):

The actual formulas are given on the publication, which I linked by editing your question. Besides, there are many publicly available implementations of Chan-Vese algorithm, including, but not limited to:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23445-chan-vese-active-contours-without-edges

https://github.com/kevin-keraudren/chanvese

http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/g-cv/

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19567-active-contour-segmentation

http://math.arizona.edu/~rcrandall/code.html

I think you could find all the details in those generously shared source codes.